# python looping through a .txt file to find a name based off its location next to @ on an email

Tags: python-3.x, file, loops

```
count_dict = {}

file = open("../dataFiles/mbox-short.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for email in line.split():
        if "@" in email:
            words = email.split()
            for domain in words:
                print(domain)
                if domain in count_dict.keys():
                    count_dict[domain] = count_dict[domain] + 1
                else:
                    count_dict[domain] = 1

file.close()
```

ive got my question im just trying to find the location of the domain name which will be the part next to an @ char in an email address, i wanna loop through the document to try and find each new domain and create a key then and a counter for every time it appears and then finally print all the keys and their worth

Comment: Is there only one email address per line and is there a whitespace (or any other separator) between the email address and the rest of the line's contents? Posting a sample of your data would definitely help.

Comment: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])
  by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
  Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3
Received: from murder ([unix socket])
  by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;
  Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
 by flawless.mail.umich.edu () with ESMTP id m05EEFR1013674;
 Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:14:15 -0500

Comment: its done by lines mate and i need to find the @ on each one to find domain next to it